# Why am I receiving an infinite loop with axios GET request and react redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am using the useEffect hook in a react a component to fire a redux action. This action makes a call to my api, but before this call happens I update the redux state, after the api call I again update the redux state. With the api call removed it works fine but with it included it causes an infinite loop

React component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { allEntries } from "../../redux/actions/allEntries";

export const EmployeeProfileTime = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userId = useSelector((state) => state.userInfoReducer.userId);
  const isAdmin = useSelector((state) => state.userInfoReducer.isAdmin);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userInfo = {
      userId,
      typeOfId: isAdmin ? "admin_id" : "user_id",
    };

    dispatch(allEntries(userInfo));
  }, [userId, isAdmin, dispatch]);
  return <div></div>;
};
```

```
import axios from "axios";

export const allEntries = (userInfo) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_USER_INFO_REQUEST",
    });
    await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `userInfo is passed as param`,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_USER_INFO_SUCCESS",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Redux reducer

```
const intitialState = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  image: "",
  userId: "",
  companyNumber: "",
  companyName: "",
  isAdmin: "",
  date: "",
  weeklyTimeEntries: [],
  entriesToDisplay: [],
  allEntries: [],
  weeklyTime: "",
  jobs: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
};

const userInfoReducer = (state = intitialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_USER_INFO":
      return {
        ...state,
        firstName: action.payload.firstName,
        lastName: action.payload.lastName,
        email: action.payload.email,
        image: action.payload.image,
        userId: action.payload.userId,
        companyNumber: action.payload.companyNumber,
        isAdmin: action.payload.isAdmin,
        date: action.payload.date,
      };
    case "SET_USER_INFO_REQUEST":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case "SET_USER_INFO_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case "SET_USER_INFO_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
      };
    case "SET_USER_COMPANY_NUMBER":
      return {
        ...state,
        companyNumber: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_USER_COMPANY_NAME":
      return {
        ...state,
        companyName: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_USER_IS_ADMIN":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdmin: 1,
      };
    case "SET_USER_IS_NOT_ADMIN":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAdmin: 0,
      };
    case "SET_USER_IMAGE":
      return {
        ...state,
        image: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_USER_WEEKLY_TIME":
      return {
        ...state,
        weeklyTimeEntries: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_USER_TOTAL_TIME":
      return {
        ...state,
        weeklyTime: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_USER_DISPLAY_ENTRIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        entriesToDisplay: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_USER_JOBS":
      return {
        ...state,
        jobs: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_USER_ALL_ENTRIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        allEntries: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userInfoReducer;
```

Comment: Seems that the effect would keep running if one of the items in the dependency array changes. Can you log userId and isAdmin in the effect to see what their values are?

Comment: I logged them and they both stayed unchanged for each log.

Comment: Also removing them from the dependency array will still cause the loop

Comment: Hmm, nothing in your code should be resulting in an infinite loop. is there more to the component than you're showing here?

Comment: Nothing more to the component, I uploaded the entire reducer file but its fairly large, I am not interacting with the state in any other way with this component so its weird its causing this loop

Comment: Could it be something with the request because with the request removed from the code it works fine

Comment: I'd probably use a `debugger` and step through it if I were you